# Debugging a C++ linker error

Tags: c++, linker, nm, casablanca

First I'll give specific details about the problem I'm having, then I'll go into the interesting results I'm getting from nm when I try to debug the issue.  Hopefully an nm guru will be able to interpret those results.

I've statically compiled the Casablanca C++ REST SDK to the library libcpprest.a.  That works fine, but when I link against my code using the command:

```
/usr/bin/c++       CMakeFiles/dcodr_service.dir/dcodr_service.cc.o 
CMakeFiles/dcodr_service.dir/viterbi.cc.o CMakeFiles/dcodr_service.dir/utils.cc.o 
CMakeFiles/dcodr_service.dir/hmm.cc.o CMakeFiles/dcodr_service.dir/grammar.cc.o  
-o dcodr_service  -L/home/user/casablanca/Release/Binaries -rdynamic -lfftw3f
-lcpprest -lcommon_utilities -lboost_program_options -lboost_regex -lboost_system 
-lboost_filesystem -lboost_iostreams /opt/OpenBLAS/lib/libopenblas.a -Wl,
-rpath,/home/user/casablanca/Release/Binaries
```

I get the error:

```
CMakeFiles/dcodr_service.dir/dcodr_service.cc.o: In function 
`web::http::http_request::extract_json(bool) 
const::{lambda(unsigned long)#1}::operator()(unsigned long) const':
/home/user/casablanca/Release/include/cpprest/http_msg.h:829: 
undefined reference to `web::http::details::http_msg_base::_extract_json(bool)'
```

It appears that _extract_json(bool) is defined in http_msg.cpp, which also appears to be compiled when I look at the verbose output of making libcpprest.a.  Now, running nm -e --demangle libcpprest.a I get the following two lines (separated by thousands of others):

```
00000000000015ee T web::http::details::http_msg_base::_extract_json(bool)
                 U web::http::details::http_msg_base::_extract_json(bool)
```

I'm new to using nm, but it appears to me that _extract_json(bool) is both in the code section and in the list of undefined symbols.  Is there a better way of interpreting the nm results?

As an aside, when I compile cpprest as a dynamic library and link against it everything works fine, but for various reasons I have to create a static binary of dcodr_service.

EDIT:
Following up on a comment from [πάντα ῥεῖ](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1413395/%CF%80%CE%AC%CE%BD%CF%84%CE%B1-%E1%BF%A5%CE%B5%E1%BF%96), _extract_json(bool) is used in the following context:

```
        return pplx::create_task(_m_impl->_get_data_available())
.then([impl, force](utility::size64_t) { return impl->_extract_json(force); });
```

That is, it is used inside a lambda function.  Could that cause a linker error?

Comment: I'd suspect you already took a look at [the manual](http://linux.die.net/man/1/nm)?

Comment: That's how I knew what T and U meant.

Comment: Not sure, but could there be some inconsistencies due to inlined code?

Comment: A static library is just an archive of totally independent object files. One object file has this function defined, another one references it. There is nothing unusual here.

Comment: Is it possible a mangling error? Try "nm CMakeFiles/dcodr_service.dir/dcodr_service.cc.o | grep extract_json" and the same for libcpprest.a?

Comment: I would suspect you are not picking up the right `libcpprest.a` file.

Comment: @n.m. Is it a problem that the reference occurs later in the library than the definition?

Comment: No, the order within the library does not matter.